# How to compress photo to send it by UDP socket in java

Tags: sockets, serversocket, image-segmentation

friends!
I want to take remote PCs screenshot by UDP scoket in java. But, there is problem with photos size! UDP packets supports maximum 64 kb and I have photo over 150 kb.

The general Idea is to see remote PCs' screen in real time!!! If you have an idea how to get this kind of result, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all I'd recommend to use TCP instead of UDP but either way why not create sections of the screen?  Separate the screen into say 20 or so sections (or hell even 200) and only send over the sections which have changed since the last time it was sent.

Also you're comparing bits to bytes with the 64Kb to 150KB.

Comment: Thank you, Eric! I have written in TCP but speed was not good :) that is why I'm tring to use UDP sockets. Because, as I know, UDP faster than TCP! And when I'm tring to send that screenshots by UDP packets there is an exception like "Large image file". So, how can I send those screenshots via UDP sockets? I will very appreciated...

Comment: General idea is to create in java server/client application which will send screenshots of client to server. So, then server side will be able to see remotely client screen! And all this stuff have to be done in realtime!!! Any ideas how to achieve this result... Thank you!